# Resizable div to both x-sides in React

Tags: reactjs, mousemove, resizable, mousedown

I'm trying to make a resizable div element. It should be able to resize to both sides. I think I came pretty close to what I wanted, but there's one problem... Whenever I click on left drag button and start to move with the element, it shift the element to the right side... I can't figure out where's the problem.

Here's the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-silence-vf1sh?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you should subtract 50 in line 30 and it stops moving the whole element to the right.

```
if (newWidth > mminStep) {
      ref.style.left = originalElementX + (e.pageX - originalMouseX - 50) + "px";
      setWidth(newWidth);
    }
```