# Recoil atomFamily not triggering selectorFamily update

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, recoiljs

I'm piggybacking off of the working code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604576/resizable-div-to-both-x-sides-in-react) to create a box (div) that is resizable on both sides (It's going to be part of a gantt chart, which is where the naming conventions of the files/variables comes from). I wanted to change this so it uses Recoil, instead of React's native state management.

First a little about what's what. There is one atom for taskIDs, one atomFamily for task properties by id, and a selectorFamily for task bar widths by id. (There are others too, but these, I think, are the main suspects).

I've gotten as far as getting all the necessary recoil state in, and everything works, except the width selectorFamily doesn't update. The program works correctly if I set the width state locally using React state, but when I instead update the taskFamily of task properties, I can see that it get's updated in the console, but the width selectorFamily for that id always returns the same value. I know there's something amiss because I have the same program components running in a gantt chart, without the resizable feature, and they work as expected.

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Code Sandbox link below(:

[image: Edit resizable-box]